# Who converts React.createElement into HTML tags?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, react-dom, createelement

Babel converts jsx to React elements using React.createElement. But it is not same as document.createElement which creates HTML tags. So, my doubt is who and when React elements are converted into HTML tags? Is it ReactDOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, my doubt is who and when React elements are converted into HTML tags? Is it ReactDOM?

Yes, ReactDOM is responsible for that. React does the rendering process to produce a virtual dom, and then react does [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to figure out what has changed. Any changes are then handed off to ReactDOM so that it can update the dom.

Note that while ReactDOM is the most common thing to use with React for updating the screen, it's not the only possibility. For example, [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) uses the output of React's reconciliation to update native dom elements, or [React-Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas) can draw to a canvas. You can even write a custom renderer if you want using [react-reconciler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reconciler), though that's very rarely needed.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for clarifying. So, whenever someone says babel is used for transpiling JSX to JS so that browser can understand is wrong right? There is ReactDOM which modifies the JS accordingly so that browser can understand.

Comment: `whenever someone says babel is used for transpiling JSX to JS so that browser can understand is wrong right? ` No, that's not wrong at all. The browser can only run JS (ie, the calls to `React.createElement`), not JSX (ie, elements like `<MyComponent>`), so babel must do that transformation or the browser will not understand the code.

Comment: `There is ReactDOM which modifies the JS accordingly so that browser can understand.` I would not describe it that way. I would say that a react app has multiple pieces of javascript which work together. I wouldn't say that ReactDOM "modifies" javascript, any more than i would say that the `.forEach` function  "modifies" javascript.

Comment: Sry, My bad in framing the sentence. I would say that babel transpiles jsx to js which browser can understand. But the transpiled output will not create DOM elements. Because babel converts jsx to React.CreateElement code which returns a js object. This JS object needs to be used/modified by ReactDOM with document.createElement to create DOM elements.